# Tabs appear on top of the keyboard in ionic 3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, tabs, keyboard

i have a tabs in my footer. when the keyboard show, my tabs appear on top of the keyboard. i want my tabs hide when the keyboard show.
is there a solution in this case?

[image: link image here]

Comment: It looks like your activity is resized when the keyboard is shown. Unfortunately  I don't have any experience with ionic, but do you have a `Manifest` file or something similar that you can share with us? If my guess is right, there is the confirmation for it.

Comment: You can find here your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57599801/7377510 . I have worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the view to not resize when the keyboard is open, the bottom of the WebView will be hidden behind the keyboard. Unfortunately there is no direct way of checking when the keyboard opens and closes (I think this is because some devices don't have a software keyboard) but you can listen for when a view changes its size, and then make the tab bar visible/invisible when appropriate:

```
rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {

    Rect r = new Rect();
    rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
    int screenHeight = rootView.getRootView().getHeight();

    int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

    if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) { // 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
        // keyboard is opened
        myTabView.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
    else {
        // keyboard is closed
        myTabView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }
}
});
```