# Keyboard is pushing tabs in ionic android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I’m developing an app on IONIC 3 and i’m having a problem. When I click on the ion search and the Keyboard opens in ANDROID it simply pushes the entire contents of the App by breaking the layout and squeezing the content.

and i`m use
config.xml

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

app.component.ts

```
this.statusBar.hide();


this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false)
```

Its WORK ! But, when i go to full screen mode it hides my bottom.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the UIScrollView from moving Up when input is focussed using **disableScroll** method.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line in `activity` **tag** in `Manifest` file
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan`

**Like This**

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

Comment: i can`t find manifest file, except manifest.json. When i put this code, always error

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css in app.scss file. I too had the same problem and I came up with this answer and this one solved me. Hope this will helpful to you.

```
.scroll-content{
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: no :(

can you share config.xml and app.component.ts, please?

Comment: I didn't add anything regarding this in my config.xml. Are you using ionic native keyboard or default keyboard plugin?

Comment: i think default keyboard plugin.

Comment: Try using replace that with native keyboard

Comment: are you using with native keyboard? can i see the code? :)

Answer (score 0):

Install Ionic Native Keyboard plugin and try below code

```
  import { Keyboard } from "@ionic-native/keyboard";

  this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe((res) => {
    this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar');
    if (this.tabBarElement != null ) {
      this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
});

this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe((res) => {
  if (this.tabBarElement != null) {
    this.tabBarElement.style.display = '-webkit-box';
  }
});
```

Hope you may help this! Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this following code**:

```
window.addEventListener('keyboardDidShow', () => {
  console.log("Keyboard is open")
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tabbar");

  if (elements != null) {
    Object.keys(elements).map((key) => {
      elements[key].style.display = 'none';
    });
  }
});

window.addEventListener('keyboardWillHide', () => {
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".tabbar");

  if (elements != null) {
    Object.keys(elements).map((key) => {
      elements[key].style.display = 'flex';
    });
  }
});
```

Add this code in appcomponent.ts or particular tab where you are facing this issue.